# Inner product in the Hilbert space

Tags: probability

For the $L^2$ space we define inner product as $\langle X, Y\rangle = E[XY]$. With respect to which density this expectation is taken, $E[XY] = \int xyf(x,y)dxdy$ or with respect to the marginal density?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expectation $E[XY]$ is well-defined even for random variables $X$ and $Y$ that does not admit a joint density (or marginal density), it is just the integral
$$
E[XY]=\int_\Omega XY\,\mathrm dP
$$ 
on the probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ on which $X$ and $Y$ are defined. It is, however, true that if $(X,Y)$ admits a joint density $f_{(X,Y)}$, then
$$
E[XY]=\int xyf_{(X,Y)}(x,y)\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy
$$
as a consequence of [the law of the unconscious statistician](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician).

Comment: Thank you, this was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Viewing $X$ and $Y$ as functions $X,Y:\Omega\to\Bbb{R}$ when our probability space is $\Omega$ with probability measure $\mu$, we have $E[XY] = \int_\Omega X(\omega) Y(\omega) d\mu(\omega)$.